# Longest Domino Sequence

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

Edit: *New code*. Both solutions were working perfectly, but for some reason did not improve my time results and that doesn`t make sense to me just yet.

Seeing my desperation, a friend PMed me his solution, which is working fine with the time given, but somehow fails on this specific input:

```
9
1 2  2 3  3 4  4 5
3 6  6 7  3 8  8 9  9 10
```

It gives "9" instead of "5". Any ideas why that could be?

```
maxNum = int(0)
idxArr = []
def ReadInput():
    global array
    global firstNum
    arr = input().split()
    firstNum = int(arr[0])
    while int(arr[0]) * 2 + 1 > len(arr):
        tempArray = input().split()
        arr = arr + tempArray
    iterator = int(0)
    array = [0] * int(arr[0])
    for i in range(1, int(arr[0]) * 2, 2):
        tempArray = [0] * 3
        tempArray[0] = int(arr[i])
        tempArray[1] = int(arr[i + 1])
        tempArray[2] = None
        array[iterator] = tempArray
        iterator+=1

def SortArray(array):
    array.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    array.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

def MergeDominos(array):
    tempNum = int(0)
    for item in array:
        if (item[2] == None):
            iterator = tempNum
            counter = int(0)
            tempBool = False
            try:
                while item == array[iterator]:
                    if (tempBool):
                        array.pop(iterator)
                        counter += 1
                    else:
                        iterator += 1
                        counter += 1
                        tempBool = True
            except IndexError:
                True == True
            if (counter % 2 == 1):
                item[2] = counter
                tempNum += 1
            else:
                tempItem = item.copy()
                array.insert(tempNum + 1, tempItem)
                array[tempNum + 1][2] = int(1)
                item[2] = counter - 1
                tempNum += 1
        else:
            tempNum += 1

def GetLengthOfArray(array):
    counter = int(0)
    for item in array:
        counter += item[2]
    return counter

def SwitchPlaces(item):
    item[0], item[1] = item[1], item[0]

def GetMaxLength(array, tempArray, left, right):
    global maxNum
    # print("This is temp: ", tempArray)
    for i in range(len(array)):
        # print("Testing: ", array[i], "Iteration: ", i)
        # print("IdxArr: ", idxArr)
        if (len(array) <= len(idxArr)):
            #print("BREAKING HERE BREAKING HERE BREAKING HERE BREAKING HERE BREAKING HERE BREAKING HERE BREAKING HERE BREAKING HERE BREAKING HERE BREAKING HERE BREAKING HERE BREAKING HERE BREAKING HERE BREAKING HERE BREAKING HERE ")
            break
        if (i not in idxArr):
            #print("Condition:")
            if (left == array[i][0]):
                #print("LL")
                if (i in idxArr):
                    break
                else:
                    idxArr.append(i)
                SwitchPlaces(array[i])
                if (len(array) >= len(idxArr)):
                    tempArray.insert(0, array[i])
                if (GetLengthOfArray(tempArray) > maxNum):
                    maxNum = GetLengthOfArray(tempArray)
                if (len(array) >= len(idxArr)):
                    GetMaxLength(array, tempArray, tempArray[0][0], tempArray[len(tempArray) - 1][1])
            if (left == array[i][1]):
                #print("LR")
                if (i in idxArr):
                    break
                else:
                    idxArr.append(i)
                if (len(array) >= len(idxArr)):
                    tempArray.insert(0, array[i])
                if (GetLengthOfArray(tempArray) > maxNum):
                    maxNum = GetLengthOfArray(tempArray)
                if (len(array) >= len(idxArr)):
                    GetMaxLength(array, tempArray, tempArray[0][0], tempArray[len(tempArray) - 1][1])
            if (right == array[i][0]):
                #print("RL")
                if (i in idxArr):
                    break
                else:
                    idxArr.append(i)
                if (len(array) >= len(idxArr)):
                    tempArray.append(array[i])
                if (GetLengthOfArray(tempArray) > maxNum):
                    maxNum = GetLengthOfArray(tempArray)
                if (len(array) >= len(idxArr)):
                    GetMaxLength(array, tempArray, tempArray[0][0], tempArray[len(tempArray) - 1][1])
            if (right == array[i][1]):
                #print("RR")
                if (i in idxArr):
                    break
                else:
                    idxArr.append(i)
                SwitchPlaces(array[i])
                if (len(array) >= len(idxArr)):
                    tempArray.append(array[i])
                if (GetLengthOfArray(tempArray) > maxNum):
                    maxNum = GetLengthOfArray(tempArray)
                if (len(array) >= len(idxArr)):
                    GetMaxLength(array, tempArray, tempArray[0][0], tempArray[len(tempArray) - 1][1])
            #else:
               # print("No condition BIG OOOF")

ReadInput()
SortArray(array)
MergeDominos(array)
for i in range(len(array)):
    #print("iter num: ", i)
    tempArray = []
    idxArr = []
    idxArr.append(i)
    tempArray.append(array[i])
    if (GetLengthOfArray(tempArray) > maxNum):
        maxNum = GetLengthOfArray(tempArray)
    GetMaxLength(array, tempArray, tempArray[0][0], tempArray[len(tempArray) - 1][1])
print(maxNum)
```

**E1**: The input is made in this weird way, because the first item of the list gives the number of dominoes, and also, the input can come in multiple rows and then I create list item pairs.

Example input:

```
5 1 2
1 2
2 3
2
17
2 17
```

And the dominoes are:

```
[('1','2'),('1','2'),('2','2'),('2','17'),('2','17')]
```

Expected result:

```
5
```

*(3,2)-(2,1)-(1,2)-(2,17)-(17-2)*

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely done.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a rewrite of your solution with one significant change:

```
if maximum == len(listOfDominos) + len(tempList):
    break
```

This prevents the code from exploring any further once it has a maximum that it knows it can't improve on.  For the example input you provided, it reduced the number of searches by 20x:

```
def find(listOfDominos, tempList):
    maximum = len(tempList)

    for currentDominoIndex, domino in enumerate(listOfDominos):
        if maximum == len(listOfDominos) + len(tempList):
            break  # we can't do any better, so why try?

        remainingDominos = listOfDominos[:currentDominoIndex] + listOfDominos[currentDominoIndex+1:]

        if tempList:
            backwardDomino = domino[::-1]
            head, tail = tempList[0], tempList[-1]

            if domino[1] == head[0]:
                maximum = max(find(remainingDominos, [domino] + tempList), maximum)
            elif backwardDomino[1] == head[0]:
                maximum = max(find(remainingDominos, [backwardDomino] + tempList), maximum)
            elif domino[0] == tail[1]:
                maximum = max(find(remainingDominos, tempList + [domino]), maximum)
            elif backwardDomino[0] == tail[1]:
                maximum = max(find(remainingDominos, tempList + [backwardDomino]), maximum)
        else:
            maximum = max(find(remainingDominos, [domino]), maximum)

    return maximum

listOfNumbers = input().split()

numberOfDominos = int(listOfNumbers.pop(0))

while numberOfDominos * 2 > len(listOfNumbers):
    listOfNumbers += input().split()

listOfDominos = list(zip(listOfNumbers[0::2], listOfNumbers[1::2]))

print(find(listOfDominos, []))
```

Give this a try to see if it improves performance without introducing any bugs in the process.

Comment: It seems much faster to me but code check gives me the same time and the result is wrong in one case. I changed the code, maybe you could find a mistake that is made in it. Thanks a lot anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
def solution(dominoes):
    if len(dominoes) == 0:
        return 0

    def get_sequence(d, sol=None):
        if sol is None:
            sol = []

        if len(d) == 0:
            return

        for i in range(len(d)):
            rest = d[:i] + d[i+1:]
            d1, d2 = d[i], d[i][::-1]

            if d1 == d2:
                if (not sol) or (sol[-1][1] == d1[0]):
                    yield sol + [d1]
                    yield from get_sequence(rest, sol + [d1])
            else:
                if (not sol) or (sol[-1][1] == d1[0]):
                    yield sol + [d1]
                    yield from get_sequence(rest, sol + [d1])

                if (not sol) or (sol[-1][1] == d2[0]):
                    yield sol + [d2]
                    yield from get_sequence(rest, sol + [d2])


    return(len(max(get_sequence(dominoes), key=len)))

dominoes = [('1','2'),('1','2'),('2','2'),('2','17'),('2','17')]
print(solution(dominoes))
```

Prints:

```
5
```

Comment: Seems perfect to me, but only helps in one of 4 cases. In the other 3, time stays the same for some reason. I changed the code, maybe you could find a mistake in it I was not able to. Thanks anyway.